# Using a regular expression to extract a file name from a logfile using Python

Tags: python, regex, logfile

looking to create a list of files accessed from a log file. Two examples of strings from the file are shown below.

.... [08/Mar/2020:19:11:15 -0700] "GET **/socview/15Ragged.htm** HTTP/1.1" 200 6564 .........

.... [08/Mar/2020:19:11:31 -0700] "GET **/socview/?C=D;O=A** HTTP/1.1" 200 13443 ..............

/socview/15Ragged.htm    is what i'm looking to extract ie. ending in a .htm .log .txt etc.

/socview/?C=D;O=A    is what i'm trying to avoid extracting.

It seems that the "." is whats causing issues, as when I run the code without searching for it, ie. the RE below runs perfectly as part of the loop shown at the bottom of this post.

```
unique = re.search(r'GET (\S+)', x)
```

However it is extracting strings I do not want. Below is the loop and RE that I'm trying to use, it makes sense to me and I cant figure out whats wrong, when ran the message below is displayed. Any help would be greatly appreciated

"if unique.group(1) not in unilist:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

```
for x in input:
     unique = re.search(r'GET (\S+\.\S+)', x)

     if unique.group(1) not in unilist:
           unilist.append(unique.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GET (\S+\.\S+)` is fine. The problem is that the `re.search()` returns `None` if the match has failed, so for the second string you provided the `unique` is `None` which does not have a `group` property.

Try the following:

```
for x in input:
    unique = re.search(r'GET (\S+\.\S+)', x)

    if unique is None:
        continue

    if unique.group(1) not in unilist:
           unilist.append(unique.group(1))
```

I do recommend you to use better variable names. For example `input` is a build-in in Python, avoid shadowing it. If the loop body grows, it will be hard to follow names like `x`.

Also, I recommend to pre-compile the regex like this, otherwise it compiles it in every cycle which is very time-consuming:

```
matcher = re.compile("GET (\S+\.\S+)")

for line in lines:
    # your loop body here
```

Comment: Thanks a million, that sorted it